# How to create a view with JSON_TABLE and BLOB data in Oracle 12c

Tags: json, view, blob, oracle12c

I'm trying to create a View from an old View, using a BLOB column (containing JSON) from the old view.
I have a statement like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new_view AS 
(
SELECT ov.a, ov.b, ov.c, data.* FROM old_view ov, 
    JSON_TABLE
    (
        ov.my_column,
        '$'
        columns
        something VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) format json path '$.a.b.c'
    ) 
as data);
```

The new view is not being populated with anything. If I convert the blob to a clob though, the view will get rows inserted. Additionally if I change the above statement to this:

```
SELECT ov.a, ov.b, ov.c, data.* FROM old_view ov, 
    JSON_TABLE
    (
        ov.my_column,
        '$'
        columns
        something VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) format json path '$.x.y.z'
    ) 
as data;
```

I get the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-40499: no format defined for binary data type
40499. 00000 -  "no format defined for binary data type"
*Cause:    The provided JSON input was of binary type but a format was
           not defined.
*Action:   Define a format for binary input.

Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

I know it is compulsory to define "format json" when using a BLOB column but after that I'm not sure. I think I'm following the format defined in the orcale [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie dokie so,

Update the select statement to the following:

```
SELECT ov.a, ov.b, ov.c, data.* FROM old_view ov, 
    JSON_TABLE
    (
        ov.my_column format json,
        '$'
        columns
        something VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) format json path '$.x.y.z'
    ) 
as data;
```

The table column I was working with had JSON data, but was not declared as so with the constraint.